# Text resize only working on part of content

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have added some javascript to my wordpress site for text resizing. It only seems to work on some of the content though (namely header and email signup).

http://test.hestiacare.co.uk/

Any idea how I can get it to apply to all of the content?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Reset Font Size
  var originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    $(".resetFont").click(function(){
    $('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
  });
  // Increase Font Size
  $(".increaseFont").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    return false;
  });
  // Decrease Font Size
  $(".decreaseFont").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*0.8;
    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably has to do with this, in `style.css`:

```
.entry-content {
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

If I comment that out, the body text resizes with everything else.  IF there is other content that's not resizing, you probably need to find similar pixel-sized entries.